# Bash script to mkdir

Tags: macos, bash, shell, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory based on a variable entered by a user and then save files there.

I thought this would be simple enough for me but I get an error message "No such file or directory" when I try to save there.
When I hit "ls" it lists the directory with a "?" after it.

I am working with an .sh script on a Mac terminal.

### Relevant code:

```
#get user input
echo "enter the collection number"
read COLLECTION
#create the directory
mkdir "$COLLECTION"dir
#calculate a checksum and save it to the above directory
sudo openssl md5 /dev/disk1 > "$COLLECTION"dir/md5.txt
```

--

Comment: Your code works for me, although I got "no such file or directory" on /dev/disk1, which I don't have on my machine.  But `sudo openssl md5 testfile > "$COLLECTION"dir/md5.txt` works perfectly.  I'm on ubuntu, though.

Comment: When you typed `ls`, were you in the directory you ran the script from or the directory that it created?

Comment: General debugging tips: 1) use `bash -x` to see how variables are interpolated and other helpful debugging info  2) check or output the exit code (`$?`) after each command in your script to make sure they worked like they were supposed to

Comment: There's no guarantee that $COLLECTION ends with a / or has valid characters... joys of bash. :) Given that your on a mac, could do it in Python easily enough.

Comment: @lindley - Glad to help.  If you've solved your problem, please accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check you script to see if you have DOS style line endings (`\r\n`).  You can safely run `dos2unix` on the script if you aren't sure.

The `?` you see in the file name may actually be the carriage return at the end of the line (since Bash doesn't treat that as whitespace).

So `"$COLLECTION"dir/` doesn't exist; `"$COLLECTION"dir\r/` does.

*Edit:*
Vi usually does a good job showing you what those special characters are.

```
ls | vi -
```

Comment: Thanks!

This fixed the problem.

 I guess I had a carriage return left over from something or other.

Comment: You can use `ls -lb` to show you the control characters in a filename.

Answer (score 1):

The only piece of this code likely to give you a "No such file or directory" error is the last line. Does `/dev/disk1` exist on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

I use `mkdir -p` when I get that error ;)